# How to generate XML from Object Type in Oracle database

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, object-type

As the title explains, how to parse data from object types in Oracle to the XML format?

So for instance, if I have an object type CUSTOMER, how one can convert the data from an instance of that object to XML text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have your object type created:

```
CREATE TYPE CUSTOMER AS OBJECT
   (NAME VARCHAR2(100));
```

It must be converted to an `XMLTYPE`, and then you'll be able to get the XML text from it with the `getstringval` function.

```
DECLARE
  v_customer CUSTOMER;
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  v_customer:= NEW CUSTOMER('Josh');
  v_xml := XMLTYPE(v_customer);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_xml.getstringval);
END;
```

This will produce the following output:

```
<CUSTOMER><NAME>Josh</NAME></CUSTOMER>
```

Comment: As an addition, if you need case sensitive xml when describe fields and type names in quotes, like  `CREATE TYPE CUSTOMER AS OBJECT
   ("Name"  VARCHAR2(100));' then the output will be `<CUSTOMER><Name>Josh</Name></CUSTOMER>`

Answer (score 3):

you can use `SYS_XMLGEN`

```sql
SELECT SYS_XMLGEN(v_customer, XMLFormat(enclTag =>'CUSTOMER')) 
INTO v_xml
FROM dual;
```

less convienient to use.. but also supports TABLE OF ... types and is "pretty printed" to include newlines in the text

ie

```sql
DECLARE
  v_customer CUSTOMER;
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  v_customer:= NEW CUSTOMER('Josh');

  SELECT SYS_XMLGEN(v_customer, XMLFormat(enclTag =>'CUSTOMER')) 
    INTO v_xml
    FROM dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_xml.getstringval);
END;
/
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CUSTOMER>
 <NAME>Josh</NAME>
</CUSTOMER>
```

```sql
create type tab_of_cust as TABLE OF CUSTOMER;
```

```sql
DECLARE
  v_customer CUSTOMER;
  v_xml XMLTYPE;

  v_tab tab_of_cust := tab_of_cust();
BEGIN
  v_customer:= NEW CUSTOMER('Josh');

  v_tab.extend(1);
  v_tab(1) := v_customer;

  SELECT SYS_XMLGEN(v_tab, XMLFormat(enclTag =>'CUST_TAB')) 
    INTO v_xml
    FROM dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_xml.getstringval);
END;
/
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CUST_TAB>
 <CUSTOMER>
  <NAME>Josh</NAME>
 </CUSTOMER>
</CUST_TAB>
```